# Python date conversion

Tags: python, strptime

Okay, I give up.
Python version 2.7.2

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datestr = "2014-01-24"
>>> displaydateobj = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%d-%m'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
```

What am I missing?  I have reviewed the strptime format strings a dozen times.

Comment: On Earth, there are only 12 months.  If your program keeps track of time on Mars then a 24 month convention makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should that be:

`datetime.date(datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d'))`?

Comment: mea culpa for my stupidity!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this would result in the same error.

Comment: @aIKid Why should it? At least, the order is correct.

Comment: @glglgl Ah, it was incorrect the last time i saw it. Will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is backwards. It should be `%Y-%m-%d`. As you have it, it's trying to put the value `24` into `%m` and failing because there is no month 24